# Boxfuse is failing to create encrypted AMI

Tags: cloudcaptain

I have been using Boxfuse to deploy my app (PROD and TEST) without issues for well over a year, but now when trying to deploy to TEST (using the same command i've always used - boxfuse run app-name -env=test), I am getting this error.

```
"Running app/image failed!"
```

and that is it. It shows up just after "Waiting for AWS to create an encrypted AMI for app/image in us-west-2 (this may take up to 90 seconds)..." and the stack trace is

```
at com.boxfuse.client.core.Boxfuse.run(Boxfuse.java:653)

at com.boxfuse.client.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:325)

at com.boxfuse.client.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:133)
```

I am not sure where to begin in debugging this as the error message is not very descriptive and nothing has changed in my AWS account/settings or app configuration/setting etc. Any help or suggested places to start would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i am having the same issue. i don't even see the stack trace. where to see the stack trace?

Comment: it prints if you add the -X option to the command (Output debug log messages). I was able to deploy an older AMI (already in AWS) from the command line so the issue seems to be isolated to AMI creation (I'm guessing it is a credentials issue with the fast-ami boxfuse role, but without more detailed error logging I am at a loss for now).

Comment: thanks! it seems mine is a transient issue. it's working today without any changes.